# My Time program does not overload. Why?

Tags: c++, class, scope, logic

I made a program that takes in times and displays them. In some cases, the user may overload a time. When I overload a constructor with time, it does not properly overload and also, the (AM/PM) becomes incorrect if overloaded. There is some logic error that I cannot find. How do I solve this and where is my error located? Want I want is that if I was to put 25 hours into a constructor, it would roll over to 1AM.

```
/**  Time.h**/
#ifndef TIME_H_
#define TIME_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
/***  Time class**  The Time class contains time as   hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds (AM/PM).*/

class Time {
    public:
    /** *  Constructor with zero values */
    Time();

    /** *  Constructors with arguments */
    Time(long long time);
    Time(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milli);

    /** *  Deconstructor */
    virtual ~Time();

    /** *  Return time as   a  long long value representing time in milliseconds */
    long long asLong() const;

    /** *  Provide a  string in the format hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds. *  For example 1:45:30:56 PM */
    std::string toString() const;

    /** *  Output the time to   an   output stream as hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds AM/PM */
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, const Time&);

    // Output a Time to an output stream

/** *  Declare ordering relationships */
    friend bool operator <(const Time&, const Time&);
    friend bool operator >(const Time&, const Time&);
    friend bool operator ==(const Time &a, const Time &b);

    /** *  Declare addition and subtraction */
     friend Time operator +(const Time&, const Time&);
     friend Time operator -(const Time&, const Time&);

private:
int hours;
int minutes;
int seconds;
int millis;
};

#endif /*   TIME_H_ */
```

Below is Source

```
#include "Time.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Defualt Constructor
Time::Time() {
    hours = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 0;
    millis = 0;
}

// Constructors with arguments

Time::Time(long long timeValue) {
    long long tempValue = timeValue;
    millis = tempValue % 1000;
    tempValue /= 1000;
    seconds = tempValue % 60;
    tempValue /= 60;
    minutes = tempValue % 60;
    tempValue /= 60;
    hours = tempValue;
}

Time::Time(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int millis) {
    this->hours = hours;
    this ->minutes = minutes;
    this -> seconds = seconds;
    this -> millis = millis;

}

// Destructor
Time::~Time() {

}

// Return time in term of milliseconds.

long long Time::asLong() const {
    long long timeValue = (long long) hours;
    timeValue = (timeValue * 60) + minutes;
    timeValue = (timeValue * 60) + seconds;
    timeValue = (timeValue * 1000) + millis;
    return timeValue;
}

// Formatting

std::string Time::toString() const {
    ostringstream  v1;
    string ph;

    if (hours <= 12)
        ph = "am";
    else
        ph = "pm";

    v1 << hours % 12 << ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds << ":" << millis << ph;

    return v1.str();
}

// Time to Output Stream
ostream& operator <<(ostream& b, const Time& c)
{
    return b << c.toString();
}

// Ordering Relationships
bool operator <(const Time&t1, const Time&t2)
{
    return t1.asLong() < t2.asLong();
}

bool operator >(const Time&t1, const Time&t2)
{
    return t1.asLong() > t2.asLong();
}
bool operator ==(const Time &a, const Time &b)
{
    return a.asLong() == b.asLong();
}

// Declare addition and Subtraction
Time operator +(const Time&t1, const Time&t2)
{
    int a,b,c,d;
    a = t1.hours+t2.hours;
    b = t1.minutes+t2.minutes;
    c = t1.seconds+t2.seconds;
    d = t1.millis+t2.millis;
    if (d > 999)
    {
        c = c+1;
        d = d - 1000;
    }
    if (c > 59)
    {
        b = b + 1;
        c = c - 60;
    }
    if (b > 59)
    {
        a = a+1;
        b = b-60;
    }
    if (a > 24)
    {
        a = a - 24;
    }
    return Time(a,b,c,d);
}
Time operator -(const Time&t1, const Time&t2)
{
    int a,b,c,d;
    a = t1.hours-t2.hours;
    b = t1.minutes-t2.minutes;
    c = t1.seconds-t2.seconds;
    d = t1.millis - t2.millis;
    if (d < 0)
    {
        c = c -1;
        d = d + 1000;
    }
    if (c < 0)
    {
        b = b - 1;
        c = c + 60;
    }
    if (b < 0)
    {
        a = a + 1;
        b = b - 60;
    }
    if (a < 24)
    {
        a = a + 24;
    }

    return Time(a,b,c,d);
}
```

Below is what I plug in:

```
   #include <iostream>
#include "Time.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Tests for user-defined methods.
        Time zeroTime;
        Time oneTime(1L);
        Time twoTime(4,30,26,72);
        Time threeTime(24,00,00,00); //Overloaded Hour
        Time fourTime(22,60,00,00); // Overloaded Minutes
        Time fiveTime(22,58,60,00);  // Overloaded Seconds
        Time sixTime(17,28,13,61); // Overloaded Millis


        cout << zeroTime.toString() << endl;
        cout << oneTime.toString() << endl;
        cout << twoTime.toString() << endl;
        cout << zeroTime.asLong() << endl;
        cout << oneTime.asLong() << endl;
        cout << twoTime.asLong() << endl;
        cout << threeTime.toString() << endl;
        cout << fourTime.toString() << endl;
        cout << fiveTime.toString() << endl;
        cout << sixTime.toString() << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

The Output looks like this:

```
0:0:0:0am
0:0:0:1am
4:30:26:72am
0
1
16226072
0:0:0:0pm
10:60:0:0pm
10:58:60:0pm
5:28:13:61pm
```

As you can see, the outputs make no sense. If I add in 60 to the minutes, then it should roll over. That is not happening.

Comment: I think you guys probably want to know what it means when I do not overload. Here is what I mean.  This is what happens when the program runs:                                                                                             
0:0:0:0am
0:0:0:1am
4:30:26:72am
0
1
16226072
0:0:0:0pm
10:60:0:0pm
10:58:60:0pm
5:28:13:61pm

Comment: Please put the comment in your question. Also explain what output you are expecting.

Comment: I put the output in my question. I am expecting a sensible output. If I enter in (4,65,13,12) into my Time constructor, then I expect the minutes to be rolled into the hours becoming (5,5,13,12), as there are no such thing as 65 minutes in an hour.

Comment: The three logic errors I can see on a quick look are (1)  the constructor that accepts a `long long` uses modulo logic, so all times will be fitted within a 24 hour period, but the constructor which accepts separate hours, minutes, ....  does not.  (2)  none of the operations correctly handle negative valued inputs   (3)   the `toString()` method deems that hours 0 through 12 (so morning is 13 hours long) inclusive correspond to AM.

Answer (score 1):

`Overloading` in C++ has to do with function overload, it's a different issue. I think you mean "hour over runs" or something.

You are dealing with this issue in your `long long Time::asLong()` function.

But that function is not used when printing. You can fix the values on input instead:

```
Time::Time(long long timeValue)
{
    setTimeValue(timeValue);
}

Time::Time(int h, int m, int s, int msec)
{
    long long stamp = msec + s * 1000 + m * 1000 * 60 + h * 1000 * 60 * 60;
    setTimeValue(stamp);
}

void Time::setTimeValue(long long timeValue)
{
    long long tempValue = timeValue;
    millis = tempValue % 1000;
    tempValue /= 1000;
    seconds = tempValue % 60;
    tempValue /= 60;
    minutes = tempValue % 60;
    tempValue /= 60;
    hours = (int)tempValue;

    //make sure hours is never >= 24
    //note: an extra day or more could be lost here:
    hours %= 24;
}
```

A better method is to also get day, month, year. Then user `long long` return value as a time-date stamp, then add/subtract to the date-time stamp.

For calculating AM/PM you have:

```
if (hours <= 12)
    ph = "am";
else
    ph = "pm";
```

This causes a problem for 12:01 which is PM, not AM. Change the code so that anything slightly over 12:00 is always PM. We assume anything `>= 00:00` is AM

```
std::string Time::toString() const 
{
    ostringstream  v1;
    string ph;

    if(hours < 12)
        ph = "am";
    else if (hours == 12 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0 && millis == 0)
        ph = "am";
    else
        ph = "pm";

    v1 << hours % 12 << ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds << ":" << millis << " " << ph;

    return v1.str();
}
```

Example of overloaded operator is your method for:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& b, const Time& c)
```

It lets you print the result without `toString` operator.

```
cout << sixTime << endl;
```

C++ function overload refers to function overloading also, for example for derived classes. See online resources.

Comment: So, I tried this out and it fixes my problem, except that the (am/pm) function is still off. Am I also missing the am/pm checker in my asLong() function? Also, would a function overload mean when I actually define a function outside of main and that being overloaded when used? Thanks.

Comment: Also, how exactly would I overload milli? I got to this step.                          
                 int add_millis = millis;
  minutes -= add_millis *1000;
  millis += add_millis;

Comment: I think it was confusing the way I did it before. It's better to do all the calculations once. See updated code. I am just using your old `Time(int h, int m, int s, int msec)` constructor, but moved it to a new function `setTimeValue`, it's used by both constructors. Added fix for AM/PM

Comment: I'm doing this for a project and I need to use the toString() operator. But anyways, I entered the revised AM/PM code and I am getting the same error. My main errors are currently that and wrapping milli around. The 1st thing you said was fine.

Comment: My logic for AM/PM was wrong, see updated `toString`. I don't see an error with millis. `cout << Time(0, 0, 0, 1001)` results in `0:0:1:1 am` as expected.